# Autoptimize and google insights

Tags: optimization

I am using autoptimize plugin for wordpress speed.
When i do speed test on google insights its showing the autoptimize files in the errors.
What could be the solution for this.
I am getting autoptimize.js file as error in "Eliminate render-blocking resources"
As well in "Remove unused CSS"
PLease have a look at the snapshot and suggest some solution for this.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There should be a setting in autoptimize to inline and defer itself. That should prevent the error, because I think it will delay any non critical css and js from loading until after the initial page load. But I was just googling about a similar thing and saw a few warnings about what is and is not critical css/js being moved around, so I wouldn't trust it too  much.

That css error you have showing can be addressed by either removing the import from the page totally, if that is possible,  or maybe split it up and only load the smaller portion needed for that page. So if you check the inline and defer option, and remove that css file by removing the import line, you should be good to go.